# How do i make a batch script find a specific file and delete it?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to make a script that deletes a downloaded file, but the path will change between computers, this is what i have tried so far but the bat file on my friends computer won't delete the file.

```
del ""C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\amongus dwld.bat"
```

any way of solving it?

Answer (score 2):

use env variable `%username%` that expands to the given user on the respective machines.

```
del "C:\Users\%username%\Downloads\amongus dwld.bat"
```

Comment: even better: `del "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads\amongus dwld.bat". It's not guaranteed that the user's files are in `C:\users\...`

Answer (score 0):

Type `del /?` for *help*.

So `del "C:\Users\dwld.bat" /s`